# Finding an Item in a Point Cloud

Tags: ros, pcl, pointcloud, object-detection, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I'm wondering if there is a implementation in ROS that would allow me to find a Object in a point cloud based off of some kind of comparison, preferably either to a Mesh object or a smaller point cloud representing the object that I'm looking for.

I've search online and it appears that there may already be an implementation, but I Can't find anything specifically documenting where it is or what it's called.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48261/finding-an-item-in-a-point-cloud/) by [Muadibz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3374/muadibz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Maybe this [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/template_alignment.php#template-alignment) on template alignment from point cloud library is what you are searching for ?
Or maybe [this one](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php#correspondence-grouping) on 3D object recognition ?

Bests regards,

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0